# Github for Windows stopped working

Tags: windows, github

I am trying to commit a repository on github through the github GUI in windows. My repository size is of 63 MB. After writing the commit message when i commit it crashes. Windows shows message as "Github stopped working". What could be the problem and how to rectify it?

**Note:** I asked this same question on SO but moderators closed it and wanted me to ask this question on this site.

Comment: Well, it's probably a bug in the GitHub for Windows client. You should try to commit the changes on the command line and see what happens.

Comment: What version of the client do you have installed?